# How to add current opened script diretory path to "python.analysis.extraPaths" in VSCode automatically?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

Python is able to do imports from the current directory, that is the reason why I think that current directory should be automatically added to VSCode extraPaths or other internal autocomplete paths.

Is there a way that VSCode handles this without me needing to add the directory or me needing to create a script that adds the current path to the extraPaths or working directory dependent solution (I would not like to do `code .` each time I change the parent directory?

Comment: I wish someone knew how to do this!

Comment: @Copas my workaround is to work with Python packages with their virtual environment. So the packages is added to the PATH and I can import any script I want. I use `poetry`  as a package manager. Is the best out there.